# react native ble plx monitorCharacteristicForService not working just quite

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ble-plx

i am new to bluetooth development.

i try to reading data from bluetooth device, with this service and characteristic uuid.

this is uuid i got

[image]

but after i connect to device according to documentation of react-native-ble-plx then
try to monitoring or reading the device (i hope to get reading data every 1 minutes or so)
but the monitoring code not working.

is there any missing step? can you give me example code?
i try every uuid characteristic but none of them working.
here is my code:

```
manager.startDeviceScan(null, null, (error, device) => {
    if (error) {
      // Handle error (scanning will be stopped automatically)
      console.log('eror device scan',JSON.stringify(error))
      return
    }

    if (device.name === deviceName) {
      // Stop scanning as it's not necessary if you are scanning for one device.
      manager.stopDeviceScan()
      // Proceed with connection.
      device
      .connect()
      .then(async (device) => {
        
        let allServicAndChar = device.discoverAllServicesAndCharacteristics()
        console.log('allServicAndChar',JSON.stringify(allServicAndChar));

        return allServicAndChar;
      })
      .then(async device => {
        console.log('read characteristic');
        
        if(manager){
          //this code is called
           console.log('this code is called')
          // code below me is no response
          device.monitorCharacteristicForService('fee7', 'FEC8', (error, characteristic) => {
            
            if(error){
              __DEV__ && console.log('errorc',JSON.stringify(error));
            }else{
              console.log('===',characteristic?.value);
              
            }

          })
          
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // Handle errors
        console.log('error connect to a device',JSON.stringify(error));
      })

    }
```